# An unhandled exception occurred while: ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'datatable'

Tags: c#, exception, datatable

I'm new with C# and I'm trying to make a small project to connect to DB but when I call the information the web site show me this message:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'datatable'.

The line that the compiler said that the problem is this

```
Books = await _db.Book.ToListAsync();
```

This is the code that I worked with.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        Books = await _db.Book.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=OSMALOSE\\SQLEXPRESS;Datatable=DB_Books;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  },

Comment: `Datatable` is not a valid SQL connection string parameter. Use `InitialCatalog` or `Database`. See https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/